# GPU-accelerating a time-intensive function with Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have a function that takes 1-3 minutes to run because it's doing some heavy lifting inside of a C++ library. The function returns a I have an ObjC wrapper around the library and a Swift extension like such:

```
extension MyCoreLib {

     func runTheLongFunction() -> String {

        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
        let buffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
        let computeCommandEncoder = buffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()

        // ???
        // return signBlock() // `signBlock` does the heavy lifting and ultimately returns a string
     }

}
```

I'm reading more into Metal, trying to figure out how to offload this computation to the GPU on the user's iPhone to drastically reduce the time it takes for `signBlock` to run.

My code has nothing to do with graphics, ML, or images which is where I'm confused.

After creating the `computeCommanedEncoder`, how do I run `signBlock` and return that string value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused: you've rewritten your code in the Metal Shading Language, or you just have plain C++ library code that you're hoping somehow to get a GPU to execute?

Comment: I haven't done any Metal implementation other than the 4 lines above starting with `let device...`. I'm importing a C++ library, have an objective-c wrapper function around a function exposed from the library, that wrapper function returns a `String`. I want to use the GPU to execute the running of `signBlock` and my `runTheLongFunction` function to return that string upon completion

Comment: You can't just shift work designed for the CPU (and written against the standard library or third-party libraries) to the GPU. You have to rewrite the code using (likely) completely different algorithms, somewhat different language, and almost completely different (and much more restricted) libraries.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Is it possible to call a metal kernel function, pass in a `char` pointer, have that kernel function call the C++ library, assign the char and then return? Or am I totally thinking about this wrong

Comment: Note that iOS will abort your GPU code if it takes more than 10 seconds to run. And it appears that individual loops only get about half a second before they are automatically aborted by the GPU. So you're limited in what you can do on the GPU -- no long running tasks!

Comment: @ZackShapiro, my impression is that you're thinking about this wrong. You can't just apply the GPU to some existing code to make it go faster. You don't GPU-accelerate existing code, you can GPU-accelerate certain kinds of task by re-implementing that task for the GPU. Typically, this requires that the task be massively parallellizable, because that's how GPUs achieve speed. You can't access arbitrary data from the GPU, as via a CPU-provided pointer. The two have separate address spaces. Etc.